# Conference Room Under The Table Power Pack Mounts

Tags: hardware

I've currently got 12 notebooks, [HP ProBook 4535s](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14044_ca/14044_ca.HTML#Overview), that are being used by a local government group for board meetings. These are used only for the board members during the board meetings and only to display the content off of their intranet web servers. So they're pulled out of their closet, setup, and put back into their closet after use.

What I'm trying to reverse engineer is something to easily mount the power packs under the conference room table. I need to be able to have someone plug these in, secure the power packs, and disassemble the whole mess relatively easily. The table already has a dozen holes in it for dropping the power cables through and we've currently got power mounted under the table, what I'm looking for is something like this:

[image]

I've seen these kinds of things around over the years used for mounting power packs in data closets. I have no idea what the heck the actual term for it would be.

So the actual question: What the heck is that thing called and where can I buy a dozen?
Alternative answers I wouldn't mind seeing: How the heck can I do this differently?

Comment: Is there some reason why you could just put velcro on the power supplies and underside of the table?  Or perhaps just put some long velcro cable ties underneath the table?

Comment: @Zoredache - Other than the fact that I didn't think about...no. No reason I can think of. I'll probably be recommending that if I cant find out what these other things are. Thanks!

Comment: If you do go with velcro, your one tricky part will be finding velcro that will stay stuck to the power supply.  The heat may weaken the glue used on the back of some types of velcro.

Comment: We've mounted them with "Dual Lock" which is like velcro but better. The black kind is really strong and the white is almost un-removable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these guys:

http://www.cableorganizer.com/cable-corral/

They're wire cages that you mount to the bottom of the table. you can slap the power supplies in there and use the cable management part to keep excess cordage out of the way.

Comment: Apparently these guys are just a few blocks away from me, local product ftw.

Comment: That's always nice, especially when it's a company that's home-grown like that.

Answer (score 3):

Zoredache's suggestion of just using velcro cable ties is good, screw some strips of velcro (use washers so the screws don't tear through the velcro) to the underside of the table.

If it was me, I'd be inclined to go for something more permanent.  Get a second power supply for each laptop and mount them under the table with something like [screw mount cable ties.](http://www.uline.ca/BL_3213/Screw-Mount-Cable-Ties)

Added: If you do an image search for "u bracket" "c bracket" or "j bracket" some of the resulting metal or plastic brackets might also be workable - you'd basically be making small shelves under the table to put the power supplies on.

Comment: I made a pair of brackets for a battery charger to allow me to wall mount it, made out of 2 angle brackets for shelves, bent over at the end to make them an uneven U shape, nothing more needed than molegrips and a hammer ;)